# Wrong MYSQL format number in Google Sheets via JDBC

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc, format-string

The numbers that I import from an sql database on google sheet are interpreted as duration and not as numbers, more specifically as currencies.

| colA | colB | colC | colD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 449 | 1234 | 29521.00 | 0.00 |
| 449 | 1234 | 29521.00 | 0.00 |

Wrong = 29521.00 (format currently imported)
Correct = € 29.521,00

What am I doing wrong in colC and colD?

function runSql(query, options) {

```
console.log('query from runSql :' + query);
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = doc.getSheets()[2];
    var cell = sheet.getRange('a1');
    var activeCellRow = cell.getRow();
    var activeCellCol = cell.getColumn();

var rs = [];
    try {
        var fullConnectionString = 'jdbc:' + DB_TYPE + '://' + HOST + ':' + PORT
        var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(fullConnectionString, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        console.log('query :', query)
        var stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute('USE ' + DATABASE);
        var start = new Date();
        var stmt = conn.createStatement();
        //stmt.setMaxRows(MAXROWS);
        var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, e.lineNumber);
        Browser.msgBox(e);
        return false
    }

    var results = [];
    cols = rs.getMetaData();
    console.log("cols", cols)
    var colNames = [];
    var colTypes = {};
    for (i = 1; i <= cols.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        var colName = cols.getColumnLabel(i)
        colTypes[colName] = { type: cols.getColumnTypeName(i), loc: i }
        colNames.push(colName);
    }
    var rowCount = 1;
    results.push(colNames);
    while (rs.next()) {
        curRow = rs.getMetaData();
        rowData = [];
        for (i = 1; i <= curRow.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            rowData.push(rs.getString(i));
        }
        results.push(rowData);
        rowCount++;
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
    console.log('results', results)
    var colCount = results[0].length
    var rowCount = results.length
    var comment = "Updated on: " + (new Date()) + "\n" + "Query:\n" + query
    if (options.omitColumnNames) {
        results = results.slice(1)
        rowCount -= 1
    }
    if (options.clearColumns && sheet.getLastRow() > 0) {
        var startCellRange = sheet.getRange(startCell)
        sheet.getRange(startCellRange.getRow(), startCellRange.getColumn(), sheet.getLastRow(), colCount).clearContent();
    }
    if (options.clearSheet) {
        var startCellRange = sheet.getRange(startCell)
        sheet.clear({ contentsOnly: true });
    }
    //sheet.getRange(activeCellRow, activeCellCol, rowCount, colCount).clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(activeCellRow, activeCellCol, rowCount, colCount).setValues(results);
    var cell = sheet.getRange(activeCellRow, activeCellCol)
    cell.clearNote()
    cell.setNote(comment);
    sheet.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(activeCellRow + rowCount + 1, activeCellCol))
    console.log('query success!, rows = ', rowCount - 1)
}

function runSqlFromSheet() {
   //var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet();
    var sheet = doc.getSheets()[2];
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();
    var cell = doc.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();



    //var sql2 = '{call P_Totali_per_Azienda(?)}';
    //Logger.log('sql2;', sql2)
      var options = {}
    console.log(sql2);
    runSql(sql2, options)
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the values get automatically converted to durations suggests that the data is in a format that makes Google Sheets consider them as duration values. This can happen if you read and write the data as text strings and your spreadsheet is in a locale that uses commas as decimal separators (as in `€ 1,99`) and periods as time separators (as in `12.00`). If you are reading the values as text strings, you may need to read them as numbers instead to avoid automatic conversion.

Consider using [ResultSet.getFloat()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getFloat(int)) instead of [ResultSet.getString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)).

Once you can write the values correctly to the spreadsheet, you can set the final format programmatically, like this:

```
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getRange("Sheet1!C2:D")
    .setNumberFormat("[$ €]#,##0.00");
```

If you always write the values to the same sheet, and get the data as numbers from the database, you can most likely manually format columns `C:D` as **Format > Number > Currency** just once, and have the format stick through future imports.

Comment: It is very strange but my SQL value is 29521.00 (and I would € 29.521,00) and with your script this value is formatted as € 1.230,04

Comment: I am located in Italy, so my Timesone in the JDBC script is: var SEEKWELL_J_TIMEZONE = "UTC" and I have the sheet time zone based in Italy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm... 29521 hours is indeed 1230 days. Please show your work and see [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: I cannot share my sheet

Comment: I have inserted my code. As you can see, I have not ResultSet.getString() function

Comment: You are calling the `ResultSet.getString()` method in `rs.getString(i)`. That is most likely the culprit.